# New coordinates after rotation of axis around origin.

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, rotations

I have a point $(-24.75665066,0.61535793,34.60714434)\in\mathbb{R}^3$

I would like to find the new coordinate after a $3\times3$ rotation matrix is applied to the axis, around the origin. Matrix example below:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.4197673 & 0.5603373 & 0.7140151\\
-0.8973154 & -0.1379305 & -0.4192854\\
-0.1364568 & -0.8166990 & 0.5606980
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This type of maths is way above my head, however trying to solve this problem is really encouraging me to go and study further mathematics. I was able to find some similar questions, but none I was able to use. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ is your matrix, and $x$ your vector, you do matrix multiplication to get the new coordinates: $x'=Ax.$

Comment: As Adrian said, and to calculate $Ax$ you treat $x$ like a $3\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: appreciate the responses, much simpler than I had imagined! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, then $f(x)=A\vec{x}$ where $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ describes a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$. 
From your description, it seems that you are working with a $3\times 3$ rotation matrix, which sends vectors (or your "coordinate") in $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. 
Therefore, to apply the transformation to your point, simply express the point as a $3\times 1$ vector, and right-multiply it to the rotation matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.4197673 & 0.5603373 & 0.7140151\\
-0.8973154 & -0.1379305 & -0.4192854\\
-0.1364568 & -0.8166990 & 0.5606980
\end{bmatrix} \times
\begin{bmatrix}
-24.75665066 \\
0.61535793\\
34.60714434\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to obtain the new vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
35.446864032260734\\
7.619376905219662\\
22.279807738857738
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: thank you so much!